# I want to remove certain tags from specific outer tag in the xslt file

Tags: xslt

I came across a scenario where i need to get rid of tags with 'if' condition within outer *Header tag* only and not the *DATA* tag .... below is the excerpt :

```
<Header>
  <xsl:if test="Name">
   <xsl:for-each select="Name">
   <Name>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </Name>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:if>

 <xsl:if test="aaa">
 <Code>
  <xsl:value-of select="xxxx"/>
 </Code>
 </xsl:if>

</Header>
<Data>
  <xsl:if test="Name">
    ---------
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="aaa">
    ------
  </xsl:if>
</Data>
```

The output should be :

```
<Header>
 <xsl:for-each select="Name">
   <Name>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </Name>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <Code>
  <xsl:value-of select="xxxx"/>
  </Code>
</Header>
<Data>
 <xsl:if test="Name">
   ---------
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="aaa">
  ------
 </xsl:if>   
</Data>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please add the code you have come up with so far to accomplish this. It does not matter if it's not working - that's the point of posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform an identity transform with an exception, namely getting rid of the `xsl:if` statement if it is a child of the `Header` element. Note that you also need to match the attributes of `xsl:if` explicitly, otherwise the transformation fails.

Assuming correct input (a document node called `root` with the XSL namespace and without the "-------" in your input XML), here is a way to do it.

For your future questions be sure to always show *your effort*, that is your own attempt at solving your problem. Otherwise people will not always be willing to help you.

**Stylesheet**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:if[parent::Header]|xsl:if[parent::Header]/@*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <Header>
  <xsl:for-each select="Name">
     <Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </Name>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <Code>
     <xsl:value-of select="xxxx"/>
  </Code>
 </Header>
 <Data>
  <xsl:if test="Name"><!--further processing--></xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="aaa"><!--further processing--></xsl:if>
 </Data>
</root>
```

Comment: The source file is itself XSLT:


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

Comment: I know that the source is a stylesheet as well. If this was helpful to you, consider marking this as an answer (the tick on the left).